# undefined method `configure' for devise gem rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In my project I'm using devise gem. Previously, I used this gem for other project but there was no problem. But now when I attempts generate this command

```
>> rails generate devise:install
```

I'm getting this error:

```
C:/Sites/downlod/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for #<Downlod::Application:0x4359ae0> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Sites/downlod/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

But don't know why?
Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'sdoc', group: :doc


gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise'
```

here is my development.rb file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

end
```

Comment: can you please post `config/environments/development.rb` file?

Comment: Have you got the `devise initializer` on your system? This would be a typical cause of this error. Also post your `development.rb`

Comment: i add development.rb file